# Git. Can't back to the commit

Tags: git

I have a branch with name task. I checked out to the commit i did one day ago like this:

```
git checkout 53ba56611358e90d4990c3a8642e46c7bc93e514
```

Then I wrote some code and commited it like this:

```
git add .
git commit -m "message"
```

Then I switched branch with:

```
git checkout dev
```

and now I don't know how to back to that branch.
When I move to the branch task, the HEAD is not my last commit, but HEAD commit is the same as commit before I made:

```
git checkout 53ba56611358e90d4990c3a8642e46c7bc93e514
```

Comment: You have to `--amend` the commit. You were not on a branch - you were in detached state

Comment: _"back to that branch"_ - you were not on a branch. You committed the code in a detached head state. Use `git reflog` to find the commit ID of the new commit you made

Comment: You made a commit while in detached head mode.

Comment: [Why did my Git repo enter a detached HEAD state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965676/why-did-my-git-repo-enter-a-detached-head-state)

Comment: **Why** did you do `git checkout 53ba56611358e90d4990c3a8642e46c7bc93e514` instead of `git checkout mybranch`?

Comment: In future after checking out a commit, create a branch `git switch -c my-branch`

Comment: Does it mean that i lost code I wrote from the moment I did: ```git checkout 53ba56611358e90d4990c3a8642e46c7bc93e514``` ?

Comment: @AnorLondo no it's not lost. You've committed the code. Use `git reflog` to find the commit ID of the unknown commit and then you can check it out, then create a branch

Comment: @AnorLondo: it's "lost" in the sense that it's not tracked by a branch. But you can fix it with `reflog`. To avoid it, read the question about detached HEAD: it tells you how to got into this mess and what to do to avoid it in the future.

Comment: "I checked out to the commit i did one day ago like this:" `git checkout 53ba56611358e90d4990c3a8642e46c7bc93e514` So the short answer is, that was a bad thing to do. You probably meant `git reset --hard 53ba56` though it's a bit difficult to tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to dig around in the reflog for `HEAD`, find the "missing" commit's hash ID, and save hash ID somewhere—probably, in a new branch name, if only temporarily.  That is:

```
$ git reflog
<inspect the output>
$ git show <hash>      # for some hash ID that looks likely
# if that's the right hash:
$ git branch temp-save-branch <hash>
```

Each of the things in `<angle brackets>` represents something you *wouldn't* type literally at your command prompt, and each of the things after the pound sign `#` is a comment (which you wouldn't type in at all).

To understand this, read on.

#### Git is all about commits

Those new to Git, as you probably are, often think that Git is about files.  It's not—though commits do *store* files (but not folders, just files!).  Or, they might think Git is about branches.  It's not about those either, though commits are organized *into* branches, and branch *names* help us—and Git—*find* the commits.  This means that it's crucial for you to understand what a Git commit is, and what it does for you.

What it *is*, is a numbered thing (of type *commit* internally, as there are actually four internal types, not that you'll normally use anything but commits and—sometimes—tags).  The numbers aren't simple counting numbers though: we don't have commit #1, followed by #2, then #3, and so on.  Instead, each number is very large, and quite random looking, and usually expressed in [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal), such as `53ba56611358e90d4990c3a8642e46c7bc93e514`.

What a commit *does for you* is to store two things:

- First, each commit stores a *full snapshot of all of your files*.  These files are in a special, read-only, Git-only, compressed and de-duplicated form. The de-duplication takes care of the first objection most people make to the fact that every commit stores every file, again and again: if you make a commit that has a thousand files, then change *one* file and make a new commit, the new commit *re-uses* 999 files.  It only really has to store one *new* file.  Both commits still store all 1000 files, it's just that 999 of them are shared.

  Because these files *are* read-only, Git-only, compressed, and de-duplicated, you can't actually *use* them.  That's why `git checkout` does what it does (which we'll see in a moment).  They can be shared because they're read-only: they literally *can't* change.  In fact, no part of any commit can ever change, including ...
- The other part of each commit is the *metadata*, or information about this particular commit itself.  The metadata is where Git stores the name and email address of the person who *made* the commit, for instance.  Git keeps two name + email + date-time-stamp triples per commit: one for the author, and one for the committer, even though both are usually the same.  Git also keeps in here some of its other internal maintenance items, and any *commit log message* the author/committer chooses to include, to describe *why* they made that particular commit.

  Critical for Git's own operation, each commit stores the hash ID (or IDs) of a previous commit (or some number of previous commits).  Most commits store exactly one such hash ID, and that's all we'll look at here.  We—and Git—call this stored hash ID the *parent* of the commit.  That makes this commit the child.

Note that the child knows its parent, but the parent doesn't know its children.  This falls out of the fact that all commits are—necessarily, due to Git's commit numbering system—completely read-only.  When we make a child commit, its parent already exists, so the child can store that hash ID.  But when we make the child, we don't know whether it will have any future children, much less what their hash IDs will be.  The hash ID of some future commit depends not only on what goes into that commit, but also the exact date and time that we (or whoever) make it.  If we try to predict a future commit's hash ID, we have to get the time right, down to the second (and, due to some fancy cryptography math, even that's not enough).

What all of this means is that Git works *backwards*.  Each commit remembers its parent, which means that commits form backwards-looking chains.  If the *last* commit in some chain has some hash ID `H`, we might draw that commit like this:

```
            <-H
```

The little backwards-pointing arrow coming out of `H` points to its parent, which has some other random-looking hash ID; let's call that one `G` and draw it in:

```
        <-G <-H
```

Of course, `G` likewise points backwards to *its* parent.  Let's call that `F` and draw *it* in:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

This goes on all the way back in time to the very first commit, which—being the first commit—doesn't have a parent, so it just doesn't bother to point backwards.  The whole chain, then, is:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F--G--H
```

where we get lazy and stop drawing the arrows *as* arrows (mostly because it's too hard in a text-only StackOverflow answer).

The nice thing about this is that, given the hash ID of the *last* commit in the chain—`H` in this case—we can have *Git itself* find *all the earlier commits*.  Git uses the hash ID that we (somehow) give it to locate `H`.  `H` itself locates `G`, which locates `F`, and so on, all the way back to `A`.  A `git log` stops after showing commit `A` since there's nothing left to show, although we typically will quit out of a `git log` long before it gets all the way back to the start anyway, in a real repository with thousands of commits.

But the thing is, Git *really needs* the hash ID of `H`, to find it fast.  It's possible, in a small enough repository, to go through *every* commit and figure out which one(s) are "at the end", but that's *hard and slow:* in a big repository with hundreds of thousands of commits, it would take seconds, or maybe even minutes.  We like our answers in nanoseconds, or maybe milliseconds at worst.  So we need to save `H`'s hash ID somewhere.  We could write it down on paper, or scribble it onto a whiteboard at work—but that's just silly: we have a *computer!*  Let's have the *computer* save `H`'s hash ID somewhere.

#### Enter branch names

A *branch name*, in Git, is just a way for us to have the computer save the last hash ID.  That is, if `H` is an interesting commit, because it's the *last* commit on—say—`main`, we tell Git to scribble `H`'s hash ID into a table somewhere under the name `main`.  We draw that like this:

```
...--G--H   <-- main
```

If we'd like a new branch, such as `dev`, now, we can just create a second name, and have that name store `H`'s hash ID too:

```
...--G--H   <-- dev, main
```

That might seem a little silly at first, but read on.

#### `HEAD` determines the *current branch*

Once we have several *branch names*, we need a way to have Git know *which name we are using*.  To let Git know, we'll "attach" the special name `HEAD` to *exactly one branch name*, like this:

```
...--G--H   <-- dev, main (HEAD)
```

We are now `on branch main`, as `git status` would say.  Or:

```
git checkout dev
```

We are now `on branch dev` because the picture has changed:

```
...--G--H   <-- dev (HEAD), main
```

Either way, `git checkout` will *extract* commit `H`'s files, for us to see and work on/with.  The files in commit `H` are, after all, read-only, and usable only by Git itself.  They're not in the normal folder-with-file form.<sup>1</sup>  So `git checkout` has to *copy* the files *out* of the commit.  We won't go into any detail here, but this itself gets a bit complicated.

---

<sup>1</sup>Git may *also* be able to store files whose name our OS can't handle.  If we are on Windows or macOS, this happens all too often: some Linux user makes a file named `aux.h`, which Windows can't handle, or `schön` but spelled with the wrong UTF-8 byte sequence so that our macOS system gets confused.  Or, they create both `readme` and `README`, and our case-folding file system can't handle it.

---

#### `HEAD` also determines the *current commit*

Note how at this point, there's only one commit to use, regardless of whether we tell Git to `git checkout main` or `git checkout dev`:

```
...--G--H   <-- dev (HEAD), main
```

So whichever one we use, we'll have the files from `H`.  But let's make a *new* commit now, while we're in this setup, just like this.  We edit some file, run `git add` for reasons we haven't covered, and run `git commit`.  Git:

- packages up a snapshot of every file, including the one we changed-and-added;
- collects a log message from us, if we didn't give it one yet;
- adds the *current commit* hash ID (whatever `H` is short for) as the *parent*;
- adds the rest of the metadata; and
- writes out a new commit.

The act of writing out a new commit produces a new, random-looking hash ID, but we'll just call this new commit `I`.  New commit `I` has `H` as its parent.  `H` was the current *commit* because `HEAD` said `dev` and `dev` said `H`.  So, once this new commit goes in the repository, the sequence of commits is now:

```
...--G--H
         \
          I
```

But because we ran `git commit`, and because `HEAD` is attached to `dev`, the *last* step of `git commit` was to *write the new commit's hash ID into the name `dev`*.  So now we have:

```
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          I   <-- dev (HEAD)
```

Note that while `HEAD` is still attached to the name `dev`, the name `dev` now selects the *new* commit `I`.

New commit `I` is the *last* commit on `dev` now.  Commit `H` remains the last commit on `main`.  Commits up through `H`, which were on both branches, are *still on both branches*.  But new commit `I` is *only on `dev`* right now.

If, later, we have Git move the name `main` forward one step—this is a little bit tricky since Git really works backwards, but we can do it—we'll end up with:

```
...--G--H--I   <-- dev, main
```

and all the commits will be on both branches again (after which we can delete either of the two names: the other name suffices to *find* the commits).  But for now, at least, we need both names, so as to know that `H` is the last commit of `main` and `I` is the last commit of `dev`.

#### Detached HEAD mode

One of the points of doing all of this stuff with commits—which save every file forever for us—is so that we can "go back in time", as it were, and look at how our software was yesterday, or last week, or last year.  To do that, we use the kind of command you ran:

```
git checkout 53ba56611358e90d4990c3a8642e46c7bc93e514
```

This uses what Git calls *detached HEAD mode*.  Here, instead of attaching `HEAD` to some branch name, Git just stores the raw hash ID directly into `HEAD`.  We can draw that like this:

```
...--F   <-- HEAD
      \
       G--H   <-- dev
```

for instance.<sup>2</sup>  Git removes the files from whatever commit we had out before (`H`, say) and populates our working tree with the files from commit `F` instead, and now we can see what our project looked like back then.

But: what if we make a *new commit* while in this mode?  That's exactly what you did.  Git's answer is: it makes a new commit the same way as always.  You make some changes, `git add` the updated files, and run `git commit`, and Git packages up a snapshot and adds metadata, and makes a new commit.

The *parent* of the *new* commit is the *current* commit, `F`.  So let's draw our new commit `I` now.  It must reach back to commit `F`:

```
       I
      /
...--F
      \
       G--H
```

That part's pretty straightforward.  But what happens to the *names?*  Well, we aren't on `dev`, so `dev` continues to point to `H`.  Git would normally write `I`'s hash ID into the *name* to which `HEAD` is attached, but `HEAD` isn't attached to any name.  So Git just writes the new commit's hash ID into `HEAD` itself, directly, like this:

```
       I   <-- HEAD
      /
...--F
      \
       G--H   <-- dev
```

If you then run `git checkout dev`, Git:

- erases the files for commit `I` from the working tree;
- fills in the working tree with the files from `H`; and
- attaches `HEAD` to the name `dev`.

The result is:

```
       I   ???
      /
...--F
      \
       G--H   <-- dev (HEAD)
```

Where is commit `I`?  It's *still there*.  The problem is, there is no *name for it*.  You will have to find its raw hash ID, and give that to `git checkout` or `git branch`.  If the actual hash ID were `abcdabc`, you could run:

```
git checkout abcdabc
```

and you'd be back to the detached-HEAD mode, with `HEAD` pointing to commit `I` again.  Then you would run:

```
git branch save-this
```

or whatever, and get:

```
       I   <-- HEAD, save-this
      /
...--F
      \
       G--H   <-- dev
```

Or, you could short-cut a bit and run:

```
git branch save-this abcdabc
```

and get:

```
       I   <-- save-this
      /
...--F
      \
       G--H   <-- dev (HEAD)
```

Since we didn't do a `git checkout`, `HEAD` remains attached to `dev` and commit `H` remains the *current commit*, but commit `I` (or `abcdabc`) now has a *name* and is easy to find.

The trick here is that you must somehow *find the hash ID of the commit*.  That's where `git reflog` comes in: running `git reflog`, with no arguments, spills out the reflog entries for the special name `HEAD`.  One of those will be the hash ID of the commit you made.  All commit hash IDs look like random junk, of course, so you'll have to rely on something else to find the *right* one.  The output from `git reflog` includes a short bit from your commit, for instance, or you can run `git show` on each commit hash ID, because `git show` will show you the commit.

---

<sup>2</sup>I've left out `main`, but probably `main` or `master` exists and therefore points to some commit somewhere in your repository.  This doesn't really matter for our purposes.  As long as you're not using the name `main` or `master` to remember some specific commit, you can even just delete it entirely.  We typically end up with `main` or `master` in a repository we clone from some centralized depot somewhere (maybe on GitHub) because *they* had a `main` or `master` and our Git made our `main` or `master` based on theirs.  But that means we have an `origin/main` or `origin/master` too, and *that* name remembers the right hash ID.  We don't need our own `main` or `master`, we can just use that non-branch-name for most purposes.  We only need our own *branch* name if we need it for "branch-name-y" operations, like making *new* commits.

---

#### Side note: `git show` shows diffs

I've said several times now that every commit is a full snapshot of every file.  Yet, if we run `git show commit-specifier`, we see stuff like this:

```
$ git show HEAD
commit eb27b338a3e71c7c4079fbac8aeae3f8fbb5c687 ...
Author: ...
Date:   ...
...
diff --git a/Documentation/RelNotes/2.33.0.txt b/Documentation/RelNotes/2.33.0.txt
index d4c56de5cb..a69531c1ef 100644
--- a/Documentation/RelNotes/2.33.0.txt
+++ b/Documentation/RelNotes/2.33.0.txt
@@ -30,6 +30,9 @@ UI, Workflows & Features
 
  * The userdiff pattern for C# learned the token "record".
 
+ * "git rev-list" learns to omit the "commit <object-name>" header
+   lines from the output with the `--no-commit-header` option.
[snip]
```

If a commit *is* a snapshot (and it is), why do we *see* a diff?  The answer is: because Git *figures one out to show*, when you run `git show` (or `git log -p`, for that matter).  If we're at some commit:

```
...--G--H   <-- main (HEAD)
```

it's easy for Git to turn `HEAD` into `main` and hence into hash ID `H`.  But it's also easy for Git to then use hash ID `H` to retrieve the metadata for commit `H`, from which Git finds the hash ID `G`.  Git can now use `G` and `H` to retrieve the *entire snapshots* in *both* `G` *and* `H`, and now all it has to do is compare them.<sup>3</sup>  The result of this comparison is usually far smaller than the set of files inside the snapshot, and also much more useful for a human.  So that's what `git show` shows.

Note that *merge commits* are commits that (by definition) have at least *two* parents, instead of the usual one.  In this case, it is not clear which parent(s) Git should compare to the child.  What `git log -p` does, at least by default, is simple, though often useless: it just doesn't bother to show a diff at all.  What `git show` does is more complicated; we won't cover that here.

---

<sup>3</sup>"All", I say, as if that's just a [Small Matter of Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_matter_of_programming).  However, the internal format for commit snapshots, with its de-duplication tricks, makes it trivially easy for Git to tell if two files are *the same*.  So Git can skip over every *unchanged* file easily.  Git only needs to run a complicated diff engine algorithm over two files that *aren't* the same, in the two snapshots.